# How do you create an array of member function pointers with arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, functional-programming, bind, pointer-to-member

I am trying to create a jump table for a fuzzy controller. Basically, I have a lot of functions that take in a string and return a float, and I want to be able to do something along the lines:

```
float Defuzzify(std::string varName, DefuzzificationMethod defuzz)
{
   return functions[defuzz](varName);
}
```

where  DefuzzificationMethod is an enum. The objective is to avoid a switch statement and have a O(1) operation.

What I have right now is:

```
float CenterOfGravity(std::string varName);

std::vector<std::function<float (std::string)>> defuzzifiers;
```

Then I try to initialize it in the constructor with:

```
defuzzifiers.reserve(NUMBER_OF_DEFUZZIFICATION_METHODS);
defuzzifiers[DEFUZZ_COG] = std::bind(&CenterOfGravity, std::placeholders::_1);
```

This is making the compiler throw about 100 errors about enable_if (which I don't use anywhere, so I assume std does). Is there a way to make this compile ? Moreover, is there a way to make this a static vector, since every fuzzy controller will essentially have the same vector ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain the correct one. Making this work is driving me crazy, as references are few.

Answer (score 2):

Reserve just makes sure there's enough capacity, it doesn't actually mak the vector's size big enough. What you want to do is:

```
// construct a vector of the correct size
std::vector<std::function<float (std::string)>> defuzzifiers(NUMBER_OF_DEFUZZIFICATION_METHODS);

// now assign into it... 
// if CentorOfGravity is a free function, just simple = works
defuzzifiers[DEFUZZ_COG] = CenterOfGravity; 

// if it's a method
defuzzifiers[DEFUZZ_COG] = std::bind(&ThisType::CenterOfGravity, this, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Now this might leave you some holes which don't actually have a function defined, so maybe you want to provide a default function of sorts, which the vector constructor allows too

```
std::vector<std::function<float (std::string)>> defuzzifiers(
    NUMBER_OF_DEFUZZIFICATION_METHODS,
    [](std::string x) { return 0f; }
);
```

An unrelated note, you probably want your functions to take strings by const-ref and not by value, as copying strings is expensive.

Comment: CentorOfGravity is a member function, so that makes things a little more difficult. Everything else makes a lot of sense (especially passing string by const ref), but I still get 100+ erros.

Comment: @BrunoAyllon added how to do that one too

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you so much. You are awesome. Wish I had the rep to vote the solution up (pretty new to SO).